# Audio issue with gTTS

Tags: voice, google-assistant-sdk, gtts

I'm trying to code Jarvis.

I'm having a problem with my audio output.

when I run the python script, it said that I don't have OS imported.

How would I solve this issue?

-Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Python script needs to [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)
 the [OS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) library

```
import os
```

Here's a few example lines you can use:

```
>>> import os
>>> statinfo = os.stat('somefile.txt')
>>> statinfo
os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=7876932, st_dev=234881026,
st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=501, st_size=264, st_atime=1297230295,
st_mtime=1297230027, st_ctime=1297230027)
>>> statinfo.st_size
264
```